# Get the value of the current node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm not overly familiar with the terminology, so I'm not even sure the title of the question is accurate but I shall try to explain best I can.

I have the below XML example.

```
<countries>
  <country name="Afghanistan" population="22664136" area="647500">
    <language percentage="11">Turkic</language>
    <language percentage="35">Pashtu</language>
    <language percentage="50">Afghan Persian</language>
  </country>
</countries>
```

I use XPath down to the language nodes (/countries/country/ and then a for-each for the languages).

```
<language percentage="11">Turkic</language>
```

Using XSLT how can I output the value of , in the above example "Turkic". I can't think of another way to phrase the question but its like I am at the  node and don't know the syntax to grab the value of this node.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `xsl:value-of` element and `current()` function should do the trick:

```
<xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
```

I don't know the exact structure of your template, but for instance the following one outputs the language names:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/countries">
    <xsl:for-each select="country">
      <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I didn't even know such a function existed. Are they not mentioned in the w3schools syntax guide at all or did I miss such functions? Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Both can be found at w3schools: [value-of](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_value-of.asp) and [current()](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_current.asp).

Comment: Note: it is not a good idea to use `//`, which means "node by that name at any depth" (descendent-or-self). Use `match="/countries"` and `select="country"` instead, which just selects the children, and not descendants at any depth. Using `//` is often considered "evil" because it can introduce many subtle bugs (from overlapping nodes) and has a performance penalty (it has to go over each and every node again, as opposed to just a subset).

Comment: Or simply: `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`

Comment: I understand that <xsl:value-of select="."/> is not best practice? Or at least I can remember reading that somewhere. Also I prefer "current()" because it improves code-readability over just a single "." Either way your way still works so have a +1

Comment: @Abel: Sure thing, thanks for pointing that out! The above template was just an example that results in the desired output. Anyways, I've edited the template with your suggestions.

Comment: @Aleski Using `.` as a shortcut for `current()` is common practice. As you get more familiar with XSLT, this and other shortcuts (such as `..` or `@`) will become very readable.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: let's add to that that `.` is not the same as `current()`. In `select="foo[. = 'test']"` vs `select="foo[current() = 'test']"`, the dot will change its focus to each `foo` element, i.e. it changes _inside_ the XPath expression, while `current()` retains its focus to the current context item _outside_ the current XPath (i.e., the context item of the current xsl:template or xsl:for-each). A small, often subtle, but important difference.

Comment: @Abel I never claimed they were the same. I try to restrict my comments to the context of the topic at hand.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: of course, you are right. I didn't mean to criticize you, I know you know your stuff, just wanted to emphasize a common misunderstanding about `.` and `current()`. Apologies if I came across too cross.

Comment: @Abel None taken. I just want to stress again, for the benefit of OP: `<xsl:value-of select="current()"/>` and `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` are exactly the same thing - says so right in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#misc-func -- It should also be noted that strictly speaking, `.` is not a shortcut for `current()`; The `current()` function is an **XSLT** function, while `.` is an **XPath** abbreviation for the context node, i.e. `self::node()`. It just so happens that when `current()` is used in an outermost expression, "*the current node is always the same as the context node*" (ibid).

Comment: @michael.hor257k: well said/summarized, that is exactly it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post, but if someone is still looking for answers to this or with minor extension to original question.

How to select the particular element value of a repeated element `<language>` based on the  attribute in the element `e.g. percentage with value '11'`. If you're having challenge in getting the value (as mentioned in the question) i.e., `<language percentage="11">Turkic</language>`

get the tag language

> whose percentage value is 11

then try below code:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/countries/country">                               
       <language>                                                           
          <xsl:value-of select="./language[@percentage='11']"/>              
       <language>                                                              
    </xsl:for-each>                                                     
 </xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<language>Turkic<language>
```